# Foreach Answer calculate score

Tags: django

I have a set of questionnaires, each with questions and each question has an answer, an answer value, and an answer weight.

I need to get each answer and multiple the answer `value.count` by the `answer weight value`

For example question, 1 answer value is `--` which is given a value of `-2` and the weight is `20` so I need to calculate `-2 x 20` and so on for each question to give me a total score of all the questions in the questionnaire.

my view so far

```
questionnaires = ProjectQuestionnaire.objects.all()

results = []
    for q in questionnaires:
        if ProjectQuestionnaireResponse.objects.filter(project_name_id=project_id, questionnaire_id = q.id).exists():     
            q_response = ProjectQuestionnaireResponse.objects.get(project_name_id=project_id, questionnaire_id = q.id)
            q_answered = ProjectQuestionnaireAnswer.objects.filter(response = q_response, answer__isnull=False).count()
            if q_answered > 1:
                q_count = (100 / ProjectQuestionnaireQuestion.objects.filter(questionnaire_id = q.id).count() * q_answered)
            else:
                q_count = 0

###### Trying to calculate here ######

            the_score = []
            for answer in q_answered:
                answer_score = ProjectQuestionnaireAnswer.objects.filter()

######  END of Calculation ######
```

Models:

```
class ProjectQuestionnaire(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
    

class ProjectQuestionnaireQuestion(models.Model):
    questionnaire = models.ForeignKey(ProjectQuestionnaire, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sequence = models.IntegerField()
    question = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.question)

class ProjectQuestionnaireResponse(models.Model):
    project_name = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    questionnaire = models.ForeignKey(ProjectQuestionnaire, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
                models.UniqueConstraint(fields= ['project_name','questionnaire'], name='project_unique_response1'),
            ]
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.project_name)

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(ProjectQuestionnaireQuestion, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    choice_value = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    choice_weight = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.choice_text)

class ProjectQuestionnaireAnswer(models.Model):
    YN_Choices = [
        ('Yes', 'Yes'),
        ('No', 'No'),
        ('Unknown', 'Unknown')
    ]
    question = models.ForeignKey(ProjectQuestionnaireQuestion, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Choice, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True)
    response = models.ForeignKey(ProjectQuestionnaireResponse, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
                models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['question','response'], name='project_unique_response2'),
            ]

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.answer)
```

Comment: Do I guess right if I say your `choice_value`s are strings like `--`, `-`, `o`, `+` and `++`? And do those strings should match the integers `-2`, `-1`, `0`, `+1` and `+2`?

Comment: Yep that is right.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add a method or property to the model. You could reuse the score calculation anywhere you are working with your models.

```py
choice_value_to_score_map = {
    '--': -2,
    '-': -1,
    'o': 0,
    '+': 1,
    '++': 2,
}

class ProjectQuestionnaireAnswer(models.Model):
    # your existing code ...

    @property
    def score(self):
        if not self.value:
            return None  # or maybe 0, this depends on how you like to calculate
        for choice in self.question.choice_set.all():
            if choice.choice_value == self.value:
                return choice_value_to_score_map.get(self.value, 0) * choice.choice_weight
        return None  # or maybe 0, this depends on how you like to calculate
```

Or you could add a property to the `Choice` as well, to get the score of the choice, if there is no need for the `Answer` to be included in the calculation.

```py
choice_value_to_score_map = {
    '--': -2,
    '-': -1,
    'o': 0,
    '+': 1,
    '++': 2,
}


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(ProjectQuestionnaireQuestion, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    choice_value = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    choice_weight = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.choice_text)

    @property
    def raw_score(self):
        if not self.choice_value:
            return 0
        return choice_value_to_score_map.get(self.choice_value, 0)


    @property
    def weighted_score(self):
        return self.raw_score * self.choice_weight


class ProjectQuestionnaireAnswer(models.Model):
    # your existing code ...

    @property
    def score(self):
        if not self.value:
            return None  # or maybe 0, this depends on how you like to calculate
        for choice in self.question.choice_set.all():
            if choice.choice_value == self.value:
                return choice.weighted_score
        return None  # or maybe 0, this depends on how you like to calculate
```

In your view you can then sum up all scores like

```py
            total_score = 0
            for answer in q_answered:
                total_score = total_score + answer.score
```

Comment: Thanks, JanMalte. Im still a beginner with Django/Python, so how do reference the property `score` with my view?

Comment: Just use it a a normal attribute of the instance `answer.score`

Comment: I've tried that, but it just prints `0` even if the question has been answered and should return a positive score

Comment: Maybe the choice values do not match exactly? And there was a typo in the code, i will update the answer …

Comment: Hi Jan. what seems to be happening. is for every question the function just seems to be adding what ever this value is `return 0`
    @property
    def score(self):
        if not self.value:
            return 0
is this because the `self.value` doesn't return a number?
So for example if i set the return to 5 it will return 50 when there 10 questions